# Most elegant way for a switch case as in C

Tags: python, switch-statement

In order to parse some args via cmd line, I've a "switch case" written with `if .. elif`

```
if arg == 1:
    ..something...
elif arg >= 2 and arg < 4:
    ..something else ...
elif arg < 6:
    ..something else ...
else:
    ..something else ...
```

above, `elif arg < 6:`
could be replaced by:    `elif arg == 4 or arg == 5:`

this get's a bit messy when there are more argument values to check.

What could be the most efficient and easy way to read the code?

Comment: @jedwards The answers in the dup target just talks about checking if the values are equal. But that is not the case here, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye The question talks about equal values, but there are good references in the answers that handle other situations.

Comment: @jedwards May be I am not able to find the most appropriate one. Can you please share the answer which can work for this case?

Comment: A switch statement certainly doesn't let you use arbitrary expressions like `arg >= 2`, so I don't understand how switch statements would even apply to your example code.

Comment: @thefourtheye, I missed the random `n<6`, which I assumed dealt with `arg` -- I'll nom for re-opening.

Comment: @jedwards Its okay, I used the gold hammer to reopen :-)

Comment: in the example `elif arg >= 2 and arg < 4:` just covers 2 conditions [2,3] that would be easily covered in a switch `case 2: case: 3: ...`

Comment: @Sandt50 Should `n<6` be `arg<6`? How would you rewrite that as a `switch` -- are you switching on arg or n?

Comment: @Sandt50 FWIW `arg >= 2 and arg < 4` could be perhaps more cleanly written `2 <= arg < 4`. You could do some hacky stuff here with lambdas, which can be used as dict keys, and even build up an object that sort of behaves like a switch if you loop over it (one of the ActiveState recipes in the now removed dup target does just this), but at the end of the day, `if..elif..else` is going to be more readable. Unless there is some mathematical relationship you can exploit, you'll have the same number of cases, and even then the simplification could apply to both.

Comment: as it stands, `-1` would pass over the `if` and first `elif`, but would satisfy the `elif arg < 6` condition. is this intended?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
def case_A():
    .. something ..

def case_B():
    .. something ..

def case_C():
    .. something ..

def case_else():
    .. something ..

{
    1: case_A,
    2: case_B,
    3: case_B,
    4: case_C,
    5: case_C
}.get(arg, case_else)()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal really is to parse a command line, use [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) if in python 2.6 or lower, [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) for later python versions. There is also a really nice little package called [aaargh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aaargh/0.7.1) that makes for some really concise code. You will need to use decorators with that, so probably save that for a later project.

Use optparse or argparse, you can use things like -d somedir or --dir=somedir. It allows you to handle both optional parameters in any order, as well as required ones.

It also will generate a help message, if the command line does not meet your requirements.